# could this usage of the article "the" be considered correct?

Tags: articles

Could you think of a condition that the sentence below could be correct?

**T**he book are on the table.

Comment: Why are you asking about the article when the verb agreement is wrong? Can you explain why you think there may be a situation where this sentence is correct and why the article is more important to your understanding than the verb?

Comment: One of my classmate just asked it and I am not a native speaker so sometimes such a situations could drive me to ask such clumsy questions as that one. I am so sorry.

Comment: Nima, it doesn't take a native speaker to realize *book* just can't get *are*.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I am so sorry.

Comment: What causes you concern about the "the"?

Comment: If you meant "is on the table", just edit your question. If that's not what you meant, then what Colleen said.

Answer (score 2):

"The book is on the table" (not "are" as discussed in the comments, but "is") is a perfectly good sentence.

Perhaps you could clarify why you fear "the" might be inappropriate.

If we are talking about one specific book and one specific table, then this is correct. If you meant that there is some unknown, unspecified book on the table, you would say "A book is on the table." If a specific book is on one of many tables, you would say, "The book is on a table." If you wanted to say that somewhere in the world, some unspecified book is sitting on some unspecified table, you could say, "A book is on a table."